# NSFileManager: Using wildcards to navigate directories

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wildcard, nsfilemanager

Hey, I need to be able to navigate in a directory structure like eg; '/folder/folder2/gehrjne/folder3'

With 'folder2' containing a bunch of random folder names like 'gehrjne', yet I need to get to eg, folder3.

Using a * in a path doesn't seem to work in NSFileManager for some reason. Just says there is no directory of such.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to get the directory's contents, perhaps recursively, then find what you're after from the results -- it doesn't work like a regex.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: see the methods associated with 'Discovering Directory Contents' in NSFileManager's documentation.

`-[NSFileManager subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:]` may be a good choice for you. then you go through the results and find the string/path/item/directory you want from the results. good luck